# Windows freezes in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing C# program in Visual Studio 2010, to build a windows application.

I have created a class named Store. And inside Store class, I have created a method named StoreLength(Store ob)

```
public int StoreLength(Store ob)
    {
        int i = 0, L = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            if (ob.a[i] != null)
                L += 1;
        }
        return L;
```

Now from other class I have created an object of Store class. And using that object I am trying to use the StoreLength method.

```
 private void buttonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int l = ob.StoreLength(ob);
        DisplayUnit.Text = Convert.ToString(l);
    }
```

Now when I am running the program, everythign is working properly but as soon as I am clicking on buttonEqual, the window freezes. I think there is some problem with in buttonEqual1_Click mothod, or in StoreLength method.

Please help.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, value of `i` is not changing inside your loop at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Oh my god, this is such an easy one, but sometimes I overlook even that!

Comment: There are other problems with the code as well, if there is any chance that ob.a contains less than 100 items. You could simplify StoreLength with single line: `return (ob == null || ob.a == null) ? 0 : ob.a.Count();`. You can also simplify the Button click to: `DisplayUnit.Text = ob.StoreLength(ob).ToString();`. Also, you might consider removing the parameter to StoreLength and just have it work with the instance that's calling it. i.e: `public int StoreLength() { return (this.a == null) ? 0 : this.a.Count(); }`, then you can just call it with: `int l = ob.StoreLength();`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with asking this question :O That it's put on hold is preventing me from asking further question. Can you who voted for it to be on hold kindly say what is wrong with this question? Or if anyone thinks that this question is not suitable for this forum, can he/she be kind enough to clearly point out which Stackexchange forum should allow such questions to be asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the `while` loop's condition is always satisfied.

Every time it evaluates `i`, it'll always be less than 100 because you set it to `0` and its value does not change.

The typical approach would be to increment `i` by 1 on every iteration:

```
  while (i < 100)
  {
     i++;

     if (ob.a[i] != null)
       L += 1;   
  }
```

The reason this causes it to freeze is because your UI is 'waiting' (in a roundabout way) for this while loop to complete.

Also, consider using a `for` loop for scenarios like this. It suggests the declaration, initialisation, condition and increment all on the one line for readability and consistency sake:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   if (ob.a[i] != null)
   L += 1;    
}
```